Machine learning for importance check of three-way interaction in a longitudinal dataset
I want to know wether the interaction between the continous variable A, the continous variable B and the group (factor with 3 levels) is associated with a continous outcome Y in a longitudinal setting. I know that the interaction between Group and A is associated with B. I tested
lme4::lmer(Y ~ A * B * Group + Time + (1|IDs))
against a model without that interaction term
lme4::lmer(Y ~ A : B + A : Group + B : Group + A + B + Group + Time + (1|IDs))
but was now told to use SVMs and e.g. check the importance of this interaction term A : B : Group. However, I am not sure wether SVMs work in this longitudinal context including a three-way interaction and a random effect (appart from the fact that the sample size is low). If they do, how? I have tried GPBoost to include the random effect, but it doesn't seem to account for such interactions. Any other suggestions?
Thank you :)

Why do you think GPBoost does not not include this interaction?

Using an SVM to check for an interaction is a first for me... What are you supposed to do? Use some polynomial kernel and compare against a linear? And as you say, this would ignore both the in-subject variation and the temporal dependence. Ask for some references from the person who suggested this...
